# I deleted a network drive from my pc. Is it possible to recover it?

Tags: windows-10

I deleted a network drive from my pc. Is it possible to recover it?
If so, please advice.
Thanks

Comment: Can't you add it again?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889071/9882907), though this didn't work for me.

Comment: Contact your System Administrator for assistance.

Comment: Is this a business computer or a personal one? Where was the drive hosted from?

Comment: Is the drive mapped as part of a logon script? If so, the simplest way might be just to logout and log back in

Answer (score 0):

You can find the history of network drives that were connected at this registry key

CLICK START, TYPE "regedit", OPEN REGEDIT, go to key below

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices**

Then use "net use" command in CMD to reconnect

Example...

**net use e: \financial\letters**

Support

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889026/recover-disconnected-mapped-drive

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/342291-lost-my-mapped-drive